# php strstr/strpost not working

Tags: php, mysql, strpos, strstr

I'm working on a quite simple if-else statement, which containes the strstr or strpos condition.

The code is :

```
if(strpos(strtolower($ofcountry),"except")){

....

}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?

Greetings Phil

Comment: First show $ofcountry

Answer (score 2):

`strpos` returns `False` when the string is not found, and `0` when the string is found in position `0`. But in an `if` clause, `0` is also `false`! How can you tell one from the other? Easy: `===` (or `!==`) operator will return false only against absolute False. Not against 0. So use it like this:

```
if(strpos(strtolower($ofcountry),"except") !== False){
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php , check first pink **Warning**

Comment: Ok great, I forgot about that one. My fault. Thank you. But what if I need to have other elseif statements? In total I have 4 if conditions and every condition contains a strpos....

Comment: Then the same answer applies... I don't understand your concern.

Comment: You would just chain the strpos with the other elements of your if statements: `if(strpos(strtolower($ofcountry),"except") === false && $test == 'bob')`

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you :D